# Reverting back to Mavericks from El Capitan

Tags: photos, macos, pages

Ever since I downloaded El Capitan I have lost the ability to Drag & Drop photos into Pages documents I am creating.  Also in Pages, Certificate templates, for example, are not able to be edited.  I can open the template but can not do anything with it, cannot edit any changes.  Also cannot edit my own created files.  I also don't like how in Photos my photo labels are not visible underneath the photo like they used to be.  I don't know what other unpleasantness might still  be in store for me so I want to revert back to Mavericks.  How do I do this?

Comment: If you want help in solving the problems you are facing in Pages and Photos, please use "Ask Question" to ask a specific question *for each* of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to easily downgrade any version of Mac OS. You have two choices here.

1. If you made a backup image of your HD before you upgraded, back up the files that have changed since then, boot from that image and restore it to your boot drive.
2. Back up your current HD, Wipe it and reinstall the previous OS. Then reinstall your apps and restore your data from the backup.

Honestly sounds more like an issue with Pages than with the OS, but since I don't use Pages I have nothing useful to suggest other than removing and reinstalling the app. Perhaps if you edited your question asking for help with Pages on El Cap....